# how to link statically qt application

Tags: c++, linux, qt, static

I have simple console application with qt core,
I used to build a project with qt 5.11 and everything was fine, but when it was over 5.12, the following problem appeared:

I build qt as follows:

```sh
./configure -confirm-license -prefix $BASE_DIR/$QT_DIR -release -qt-pcre -qt-zlib -optimize-size -static -no-opengl -no-openssl -opensource -nomake tests -nomake examples -no-gui -no-widgets -no-dbus -no-accessibility
```

qt is successfully built, but when I build my application with the static flag, it starts to require dynamic libraries (although this should not be, and everything was fine with qt 5.11) and is not going to happen because of this.

```sh
export PATH=$PATH:$BASE_DIR/$QT_DIR
$BASE_DIR/$QT_DIR/bin/qmake -r QMAKE_LFLAGS+="-static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++" $BASE_DIR/CQtDeployer.pro
```

Here is the build error:

```sh
g++ -static -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--gc-sections -o build/release/cqtdeployer main.o   -L/media/D/own/Console-QtDeployer/QuasarAppLib/build/release -lQuasarApp -L/media/D/own/Console-QtDeployer/Deploy/build/release -lDeploy -L/media/D/own/Console-QtDeployer/pe/pe-parser-library/build/release -lpe-parser-library -L/media/D/own/Console-QtDeployer/staticQt/lib -lQt5Core -lm /media/D/own/Console-QtDeployer/staticQt/lib/libqtpcre2.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so -lpthread   
/usr/bin/ld: attempted static link of dynamic object `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'build/release/cqtdeployer' failed
make[1]: *** [build/release/cqtdeployer] Error 1
make[1]: выход из каталога «/media/D/own/Console-QtDeployer/CQtDeployer»
Makefile:178: recipe for target 'sub-CQtDeployer-make_first-ordered' failed
make: *** [sub-CQtDeployer-make_first-ordered] Error 2
```

**UPDATED**

This is more like a qmake bug.
The fact is that I changed the list of libraries necessary for linking in my makefile to

```
LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS) -L/media/D/own/Console-QtDeployer/QuasarAppLib/build/release -lQuasarApp -L/media/D/own/Console-QtDeployer/Deploy/build/release -lDeploy -L/media/D/own/Console-QtDeployer/pe/pe-parser-library/build/release -lpe-parser-library -L/media/D/own/Console-QtDeployer/staticQt/lib -lQt5Core -lm /media/D/own/Console-QtDeployer/staticQt/lib/libqtpcre2.a -ldl -lglib-2.0 -lpthread
```

and it all worked, I got the right binary.

before editing was:

```
CC            = gcc
CXX           = g++
DEFINES       = -DWITHOUT_BASE_TESTS -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB
CFLAGS        = -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -D_REENTRANT -fPIC $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -pipe -O2 -std=gnu++1y -Wall -W -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -D_REENTRANT -fPIC $(DEFINES)
INCPATH       = -I. -I../QuasarAppLib -I../Deploy -I../pe/pe-parser-library/include -I../staticQt/include -I../staticQt/include/QtCore -I. -I../staticQt/mkspecs/linux-g++
QMAKE         = /media/D/own/Console-QtDeployer/staticQt/bin/qmake
DEL_FILE      = rm -f
CHK_DIR_EXISTS= test -d
MKDIR         = mkdir -p
COPY          = cp -f
COPY_FILE     = cp -f
COPY_DIR      = cp -f -R
INSTALL_FILE  = install -m 644 -p
INSTALL_PROGRAM = install -m 755 -p
INSTALL_DIR   = cp -f -R
QINSTALL      = /media/D/own/Console-QtDeployer/staticQt/bin/qmake -install qinstall
QINSTALL_PROGRAM = /media/D/own/Console-QtDeployer/staticQt/bin/qmake -install qinstall -exe
DEL_FILE      = rm -f
SYMLINK       = ln -f -s
DEL_DIR       = rmdir
MOVE          = mv -f
TAR           = tar -cf
COMPRESS      = gzip -9f
DISTNAME      = cqtdeployer1.0.0
DISTDIR = /media/D/own/Console-QtDeployer/CQtDeployer/.tmp/cqtdeployer1.0.0
LINK          = g++
LFLAGS        = -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--gc-sections
LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS) -L/media/D/own/Console-QtDeployer/QuasarAppLib/build/release -lQuasarApp -L/media/D/own/Console-QtDeployer/Deploy/build/release -lDeploy -L/media/D/own/Console-QtDeployer/pe/pe-parser-library/build/release -lpe-parser-library -L/media/D/own/Console-QtDeployer/staticQt/lib -lQt5Core -lm /media/D/own/Console-QtDeployer/staticQt/lib/libqtpcre2.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so -lpthread   
AR            = ar cqs
RANLIB        = 
SED           = sed
STRIP         = strip
```

my pro file:

```
#
# Copyright (C) 2018-2019 QuasarApp.
# Distributed under the lgplv3 software license, see the accompanying
# Everyone is permitted to copy and distribute verbatim copies
# of this license document, but changing it is not allowed.
#

QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++14 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which as been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

CONFIG(release, debug|release): {
    DESTDIR="$$PWD/build/release"
} else {
    DESTDIR="$$PWD/build/debug"
}

include('$$PWD/../QuasarAppLib/QuasarLib.pri')
include('$$PWD/../Deploy/Deploy.pri')
include('$$PWD/../pe/pe-parser-library/pe-parser-library.pri')


TARGET = cqtdeployer

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \


win32: RC_ICONS = $$PWD/../res/icon.ico
```

maybe you need to configure qmake in some special way?

Comment: Have you built the library statically or dinamically?

Comment: Looks like configure did not do its job.  Did you configure in a clean directory?  Look through the makefile and find out where `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so` is coming from, maybe that will help find out how to stop it.

Comment: yes i build my app and qt is statically, see my configure and qmake

Comment: it looks more like a qmake bug, I updated the question in this regard